# Copying a Bash array fails

Tags: arrays, bash

Assigning arrays to variables in Bash script seems rather complicated:

```
a=("a" "b" "c")
b=$a

echo ${a[0]} 
echo ${a[1]}

echo ${b[0]} 
echo ${b[1]}
```

leads to

```
a 
b 
a
```

instead of

```
a
b
a
b
```

Why? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 78):

If you want to *copy* a variable that holds an array to another name, you do it like this:

```
a=('a' 'b' 'c')
b=( "${a[@]}" )
```

Comment: **Beware of the sideffects**:  This renumbers the keys of the array/assoc-array, see:
`a=(); a[1]=x; a[3]=y; a[5]=z; b=("${a[@]}"); declare -p a b`
gives
`declare -A a='([1]="x" [3]="y" [5]="z" )';
declare -a b='([0]="x" [1]="y" [2]="z")'`
and
`a=([a]=x [b]=y [c]=z); b=("${a[@]}"); declare -p a b`
gives
`declare -A a='([a]="x" [b]="y" [c]="z" )';
declare -a b='([0]="x" [1]="y" [2]="z")'` (`;` added for better readability)

Comment: also if a is empty then b will have an item with empty content.

Comment: 8 years later, but could you please explain what you mean by *reassign*? According to my tests and the manual, the array contents actually are copied. `"${a[@]}"` expands to a list of words (one word for each array member), enclosing that list in `( )` makes for a suitable RHS which can be used in an assignment, and `b=...` finally carries out the assignment. I can't see how `a` could lose its contents during this, which the term *reassign* implies. Did I miss something?

Comment: You didn't miss anything. I can understand why you have a more nuanced definition of _reassign_ in mind, but I think OP (at least at the time) didn't care about the old name `a` and just wanted to know how to get _all_ the values from `a` into `b`.

Answer (score 24):

### Why?

If `a` is an array, `$a` expands to the first element in the array.  That is why `b` in your example only has one value.  In bash, variables that refer to arrays aren't assignable like pointers would be in C++ or Java.  Instead variables *expand* (as in Parameter Expansion) into strings and those strings are copied and associated with the variable being assigned.

### How can I fix it?

To copy a sparse array that contains values with spaces, the array must be copied one element at a time by the indices - which can be obtained with ${!a[@]}.

```
declare -a b=()
for i in ${!a[@]}; do
    b[$i]="${a[$i]}"
done
```

From the bash man page:

> It is possible to obtain the keys (indices) of an array  as  well  as  the  values.
>   ${!name[@]}  and ${!name[*]} expand to the indices assigned in array variable name.
>   The treatment when in double quotes is similar to  the  expansion  of  the  special
>   parameters @ and * within double quotes.

Here's a script you can test on your own:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a a=();
a[1]='red hat'
a[3]='fedora core'

declare -a b=();

# Copy method that works for sparse arrays with spaces in the values.
for i in ${!a[@]}; do
    b[$i]="${a[$i]}"
done

# does not work, but as LeVar Burton says ...
#b=("${a[@]}")

echo a indicies: ${!a[@]}
echo b indicies: ${!b[@]}

echo "values in b:"
for u in "${b[@]}"; do
    echo $u
done
```

Prints:

```
a indicies: 1 3
b indicies: 1 3  # or 0 1 with line uncommented
values in b:
red hat
fedora core
```

This also works for associative arrays in bash 4, if you use `declare -A` (with capital A instead of lower case) when declaring the arrays.

Comment: `b=( "${a[@]}" )` copies elements with spaces. See [Special Parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html)

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't support sparse arrays.